# How many worker roles and web roles can you have per Azure subscription?

Tags: azure

How many worker roles and web roles can you have per Azure subscription?

a. 1 worker role and 1 web role

b. 10 in total

c. 11 in total

d. Unlimited

Is Windows Azure only work for .NET?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582598/how-many-roles-can-you-have-per-azure-instance

Comment: it does not answer the question :/ For example in one subscription can i create 50 services and every one has 50 web roles and 50 worker roles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**: I updated this to reflect the changes from September, 2011, increasing role count from 5 to 25.

A subscription is not capped by role-count. Each hosted service may have up to 25 roles (see [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/09/01/number-of-roles-allowed-in-windows-azure-deployments-increased-to-25.aspx) for clarification), with a mix of Web, Worker, and VM Roles. By default, a subscription is limited to six hosted services, and a total of 20 Small instances (e.g. 20 cores) across the entire subscription. You can mix and match VM sizes but you'll initially be capped at 20 cores. You can contact customer support to get both the hosted service count and the instance count lifted (I work with ISVs who go well beyond 20 instances).

Windows Azure is not limited to .net apps. The VMs themselves are based on Windows Server 2008 SP2 and 2008 R2. You can easily run Java, PHP, and python apps, for example. Launch Jetty or Tomcat, run servers such as MongoDB, etc. Take a look at the Windows Azure [Interop page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/interop/) for more info.

Comment: What is the correct answer of this: How many worker roles and web roles can you have per subscription? a. 1 worker role and 1 web role b. 10 in total c. 11 in total d. Unlimited

Comment: @user224763 - remember that your subscription has hosted services, each of which has roles, each of which has instances. As I said above, you're capped at 6 hosted services (which can be increased), each of which can have up to 5 roles, with those roles having any number of instances you want (capped initially at 20 until you apply for an increase).  Remember also that a role is not an instance - it's what goes into an instance. One role scales to many instances.

Comment: I'd say unlimited in terms of your credit with Microsoft. If Microsoft says you're good for 1000 instances, then unlimited=1000 instances.

Comment: In terms of Roles per subscription - this *is* capped per subscription (it's how Microsoft manages growth in data centres).  You can put in a billing support request to increase the number of roles per subscription, but there is a hard limit of how many resources you can have per subscriptoin, whether roles, storage accounts, databases, etc.  Of course there isn't any limit to the number of subscriptions you can create - but you may find that space in your desired DC limits the pace of growth.

Answer (score 1):

Azure you get X number of instances.

- An instance can be a web role or a worker role.
- You can have one role per instance.
- You can have as many instances you can afford per subscription.

So the answer to the question in your comment is yes.

But it is probably not a good idea since it would increase your cost. You would have 5000 instances  and it would cost 600 USD per hour (last time I checked it was 0.12 USD per hour)

Better to install all services on one web role and one worker role instance, and then increase the number as needed.

Comment: "Better to install all services on one web role and one worker role instance, and then increase the number as needed." - not necessarily. You can optimize cost this way, but you're also impacting the ability to scale specific functionality. The decision needs to be based on scale-units, as well as number of endpoints needed (since you have max. 5 per role, less if using remote desktop). That said, I concur that combining functionality into a single role is a great cost optimizer. I blogged about this - http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/02/azure-tip-overload-your-web-role-for.html.

Answer (score 1):

in each subscription you have 6 hosted accounts and 5 storage accounts.
by defualt each hosting account can use up to 20 instances (any size).
each instance can serve a worker or web role
in the calculation note that the same role must served in at least 2 instances to have active 
sla for the service and you can use up to 20 instances for a role (only the available per hosting account).
A single web role can serve many web applications.
The same about worker role.
So the instance count is for performance (web servers in your farm) not .net application count you create.
What client has 5000 servers?(instance is server 2008 R2 VM not .net application)

Hope that helps